# Windows Setup: Error establishing a database connection

Tags: php, mysql, apache, local-installation

I have MySQL `8.0.12`, PHP `v7.3.2 64Bit` and Apache `2.4.38 64Bit` installed. In theory I have everything that is needed to run WordPress locally.

Through MySQL Workbench, I have tried the Host, Port, User and Password I have set up in `wp-config.php` and I am able to connect without any problems.

For some reason however, when I navigate to my site's `wp-admin/install.php` I get the following:

[image: error]

In my `hosts` file, I have `dev.nativeleaf.co.uk` set up to point at `127.0.0.1`, along with `localhost`.

In my `php.ini` file I have uncommented `extension=mysqli` and `extension_dir = "ext"`

I also have done the steps necessary to get Apache dealing with PHP files, e.g. loading the `php7_module` and the `AddType` in `httpd.conf`

I also disabled all Firewalls on Windows, but still nothing! I'm so confused, I don't know why this isn't working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the MySQL port in wp-config? Typical installs use 3306. Did you change this during the install?

Comment: I did yes, I am using `3307`, so I have the host as `localhost:3307`.

Comment: and you're sure mysqli connections in PHP actually work and all the necessary stuff is setup? e.g. PHPMyAdmin or a basic test PHP script connect? Keep in mind this site is for WP development, server dev ops would be better elsewhere. What did you use to set up a local environment? Have you tried one of the existing WP oriented solutions out there that handle all of this for you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your wp is not connecting with database. There can be some reasons.
1. username, password and host from database are not correct.
2. Check mysql connection in PHP by some small php script for mysql connection.

As you told you have followed #1. Then try to check mysql connection in PHP. There should be mysql mod install in your PHP setup.

In windows try with Xampp.